# Rails Tutorial Chapter 6 create user error "SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('leewhite128@gmail.com') LIMIT 1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am following the rails tutorial and when I try to make a user through the rails console, this error

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('leewhite128@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
```

This is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true,     length: { maximum: 50 } 

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
    length: { maximum: 255 },
    format: { with: /VALID_EMAIL_REGEX/ },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: What are you typing in the console that triggers this error?

Comment: That line is not an error, it is a SQL statement. Can you please post the whole error description? Without the stacktrace nobody will be able to guess what went wrong while performing that statement.

Comment: Thanks! i actually figured it out... I had no idea that thats SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've provided, the error you're getting is because there's already a user in your DB with the email address and you have a uniqueness validation on the `:email` field so you can't save another record with the same email.

That's my best guess, if it's wrong, do as others have asked and provide more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but I think this line:

```
format: { with: /VALID_EMAIL_REGEX/ },
```

should be

```
format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
```